# how to create a coloring system with drag and drop

Tags: colors, drag-and-drop

I want to create an application for my children, a coloring system with drag and drop but I can not find a tutorial, someone he would like a link to a tutorial please

Answer (score 0):

You can find something usefull using the link below.

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/